# Do people with a high reputation get more money?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am curious if having a good reputation on SO and having a "good career" / a good job are correlated. Are there some surveys that were done ?

Comment: I know a person who has about 27,140 less rep than me and earns 7 times more :)

Comment: My friend doesn't have a Stack Overflow account, and he earns more. He's a pilot by the way.

Comment: Correlation of "good job" and "more money" is a specifically capitalist view. A lot of people, especially as they get older, value their comfort and enjoyment as high or higher than their wage [citation needed]

Comment: Reputation points on stackoverflow are way too easy to manipulate, they're in no way tied to any of the factors that raise your paycheck (your age, your experience, who you know, where you live, your personality, your gender, your education, publications and products tied to your name, luck, etc.).

Comment: If you have a good showing in your profile and you cannot negotiate an extra 5 or 10K on the average job offer then you're doing it wrong.  Not unusual btw, programmers tend to not be very good negotiators.  Or prefer not to be when it is about money.

Comment: @HansPassant That's highly dependant on where you live. In my experience, mentioning in an interview that you use SO is a positive thing, but I've never had follow-up questions on it. Lots of people simply know the site as "it's where I go when I have a problem" and are oblivious to the people behind all the content.

Comment: Yes, didn't you know? Jon Skeet is in Forbes.

Comment: In the very early days it could be reasonably argued that *rep from answers* would convey some correlation with knowledge about a topic. Over the last last six years any correlation between rep and expert knowledge has been completely erased to the point that rep is considered *unicorn points*, or *imaginary internet points*.

Comment: for those who marked the question as duplicate (@hichris), I have seen the question before asking and thought it was different. Im not asking how to make money from a rep, Im asking if there are some stats in true life . And I don't understand the downvotes. is this to make me lose money in real life ? :)

Answer (score 8):

There's unlikely to be a direct, simplistic correlation of "more repz = more salary".

High SO rep can work as a door-opener, something to make you stand out to a potential employer in a crowd of applicants.

But if the employer is at all competent, all the rest is  negotiated by looking at the candidate's actual track record and knowledge rather than an imaginary internet number.

That said - Stack Exchange's compensation scheme, for example, [does take "public artifacts" into account when determining salary](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator), and that includes Stack Overflow activity.

Their idea is that through a publicly visible track record, you become more valuable as an employee, and that has to be reflected in your salary. (More [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/08/podcast-72-jay-doesnt-get-a-raise-in-this-podcast/).)

But I doubt whether they really look at the specific reputation count (rather than the track record) even there, once it is determined that it is reasonably high. We all know that quantity in SO contributions doesn't need to equal quality.

Comment: are there that many "false positive" ? i.e people with a high rep but not so smart relatively to their colleagues ?

Comment: @Thomas I've seen a couple who essentially have "earned" their rep by answering trivial jQuery questions, yes. The top ranks seem reliably pretty knowledgeable people though, as far as I can see, for some reason

Comment: @Thomas I think I got most of my rep thanks to java.util.Date and Calendar being poorly designed... That does not make me a rockstar. I recently stumbled upon [Stackrating](http://stackrating.com) which seems to be a bit better measurement of one's potential - but still none of these have direct influence on one's salary...

Comment: @ppeterka Nope; as Hans hinted at earlier - that fully depends on how good you are at a personal sales pitch to be able to push negotiatons into your favor. SO rep is only a resource you might use. But most likely are unable to, because communicating is a skill you don't develop by hammering out code :)